# Sources for values for realistic thrust calculation exercise?

Tags: propulsion, engines, physics, thrust, rocket-equation

I want to use this simplified equation to calculate the thrust of multiple different real engines:

$$F = \dot{m}  V_e + (p_e - p_0)  A_e$$

Source: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rockth.html

Now my problem is that it is hard to find Values like $V_e$, $p_e$ and $A_e$.
Does anybody know where to find these values for multiple different engines?

Maybe some sort of database out there?

Or is there an easy way to compute them?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You usually have to estimate them on your own or google them up. Well documented engines like the SSME and F1 will give the nozzle exit diameters so you can calulate the exit plane area. If you know the specific impulse you can get the effective exhaust velocity. If the vacuum and sea-level thrust is given, you can back out some values. Example here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46548/6944

Comment: I added [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) to your equation, can you double check that it's okay? *Thanks!*

Comment: Thank you very much looks way better now