# Calculate Thrust of Rocket Nozzle - Off Design

Tags: nozzle

I have designed a nozzle for the following input parameters

- $p_{combustion}=p_c=200*10e5 Pa$
- $T_{combustion}=T_c=2800 K$
- $F=70 kN$
- $\kappa=1,2$
- $R = 330 J/kgK$
- I assume that all my gas properties stay constant for this calculation.

The nozzle shall be working ideal at

- $p_{exit}=p_{ambient}=54048 Pa$

For having no losses this gives me
$$v_e=\sqrt{\frac{2\kappa}{\kappa-1}  R  T_c  (1-\frac{p_{exit}}{p_{c}})^{\frac{\kappa-1}{\kappa} } } =  2636 \frac{m}{s}$$

Since I know my thrust for ideal expansion this gives me the mass flow
$$\dot{m}=F/v_e=26.55 \frac{kg}{s}$$

For the throat temperature I use:
$$T_t=\frac{2T_{c} }{\kappa+1}=2545 K$$
And throat pressure:
$$p_t=p_c*(2/(\kappa+1))^{\frac{\kappa}{\kappa-1}}=1.1289*10^7 Pa$$

And density:
$$\rho_t=\frac{p_t}{R T_t} = 13.44 kg/m^3$$

So my throat area will be
$$A_t=\frac{\dot{m}}{\rho_t \sqrt{\kappa R T_t}}=0.00196777 m^2$$

I hope I haven't done any mistake. **Now** I **freeze** my nozzle's **geometry** for Off-Design calculation.

1. When I use now my nozzle @SeaLevel Pressure , does my exit velocity $v_e$ change?
   To my mind not, because my backpressure of $p_{ambient}=101325 Pa$ is still so much lower than my combustion pressure (critical pressure ratio p_ambient/p_c=0.005< 0.53 is still valid)
2. As long as my nozzle geometry is fixed and the flow choked,  then $v_e$ $A_e$ and $p_e$ don't change. Can I just use
   $$ F = \dot{m} v_e + A_e (p_e - p_{ambient} )$$

In this case, my thrust will be ruduced since $p_{ambient} > p_e $.

Is this correct?

Thank you very much for your help guys!

Best regards
Lucas

Comment: I dont care to find sources so Im writing a comment instead of an answer:  yes, with a frozen nozzle geometry, you can use that equation ([the rocket equation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rockth.html)) to compute off-design thrust.

Answer (score 1):

To a first approximation, exit velocity does not change with changes in ambient pressure, only with throttle setting.

For a worked-out example of thrust vs altitude, see https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46548/6944